# React setState not immediately updating component view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a input field that is filtering the elements on of an array.

The search results are always one keystroke behind, I assume because setState doesn't instantly update the view? What's the best way to work around that?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      images:[],
      searchfield: '',
      filteredImages:[],
      suggestedKeywords:[],
      inputValue: ''
    }
  }

  onSearchChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({searchfield: event.target.value});
    this.setState({inputValue: event.target.value});
    let filteredImages = this.state.images.filter(image => {
      return image.labels.includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
    });
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({filteredImages});
  }
}

const SearchBox = ({searchfield, searchChange, inputValue}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
      type="search"
      value={inputValue}
      onChange={searchChange}
      placeholder="Search images..."
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are correct in your assumption. Collect the new `seachInput`, `inputValue` and `filteredImages` in a new object called e.g. `newState` and set that all at once the last thing you do in `onSearchChange`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The search results are always one keystroke behind, I assume because setState doesn't instantly update the view? What's the best way to work around that?

That isn't the problem.

Your problem is that you are assuming updates to setState occur instantly.

```
this.setState({searchfield: event.target.value}); //You update searchfield here
return image.labels.includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase()); 
//but this.state.searchfield doesn't reflect the update yet!
```

So instead, simply work off of the updated value rather than the one from the store.

```
return image.labels.includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: This was it. Thanks.

Comment: As a note, if you ever want to execute something only AFTER the setState has finished, you can pass a callback to this.setState({inputValue: event.target.value},() => { doSomething() })

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asynchronous, so you will be filtering by the old `searchfield` when you do `this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase()`. With this in mind you could do something like this instead:

```
onSearchChange = (event) => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  const newState = {
    searchField: value,
    inputValue: value
  };

  newState.filteredImages = this.state.images.filter(image => {
    return image.labels.includes(value.toLowerCase());
  });

  this.setState(newState);
}
```